# Why is bcmath in php 4.3 so much faster than php 5+?

Tags: php, performance, bcmath

Decided to run a quick test to see how `bcmath` operates on various versions of PHP, and noticed that the latest and greatest is lacking significantly in speed when compared to 4.3,

I am wondering if anyone knows what the reason behind this is, and/or how the speed can be improved on 5+ so that it is reasonably comparable to 4.3.

Also note, the memory consumption from 5.6+ is triple that which 4.3 requires for the same operation :

[Performance Test Results (Waterflow)](http://3v4l.org/BEfoC/perf#tabs)

Comment: if you read the waterflow at the top (graph portion), the ups and downs show that it is not cumulative. Each version is calculated on it's own `microtime()` and memory required for that version. Note the drop-offs at 5.1.4-5.1.6, and 5.4.

Comment: But see that for empty file http://3v4l.org/BEfoC/perf#tabs - graphs have the same shape. So don't you think it's a startup time that increased not the execution time? Compare to http://3v4l.org/unrRL

Comment: @zerkms - Agreed, it is php overall which has slowed down and increased in base memory usage, not the specific functions. -- according to your test, php 5.5.9 is 4 times slower than php 4.3.0, and consumes 4 times as much base memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not faster. The graphs you see include not only the `bcmath` call, but the startup & shutdown overhead as well.

```
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; ++$i) {
    bcdiv(40075036, 86164.098903691, 40);
}

echo microtime(true) - $start;
```

This snippet would measure the `bcdiv` performance: http://3v4l.org/unrRL

As you can see - the performance is pretty much the same.

A note: you can see that the numbers are really small, it means that you cannot completely trust them and you should understand that any additional load on the machine can affect the test results.

Comment: ok, that explains the specific function `bcdiv`, however, what gives with the startup ?  modules have changed and gotten faster and less memory consumptive --- at least that was the assumption.

Comment: @Sanuel Jackson: we have no idea how they actually run and measure things. So it's speculative to base something on their numbers

Comment: I too can verify that the startup of php 5.5 (at least), takes approx 0.04 s  to initiliaze (locally tested) --- also, here is a public test >>  http://3v4l.org/htt31

Comment: Should the first two constant be `strings` instead of `int` and `float`?

Comment: @theking2 they should be, I just used the exact call as-is from the question

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity. I decided I don't need the absurd accuracy of bcmath but do want to save myself from IEEE 754 rounding anomalies and created my own very simple FixedNumber class:

```
class FixedNumber {
  private static $radix = [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 10,
    2 => 100,
    3 => 1000,
    4 => 10000,

  ];
  private int $decimal_places;
  public function __construct(
    protected int $value,
    int $decimal_places=2
  ) 
  {
    $this->decimal_places = $decimal_places;
  }
  public function __toString() {
    return sprintf('%.'.$this->decimal_places.'f', $this->value/self::$radix[$this->decimal_places]);
  }
  public function __toFloat() {
    return $this->value/self::$radix[$this->decimal_places];
  }
  public function __add(FixedNumber $other) {
    if ($this->decimal_places != $other->decimal_places) {
      throw new Exception('Cannot add FixedNumber with different decimal places');
    }
    return new FixedNumber($this->value + $other->value, $this->decimal_places);
  }
  public function __sub(FixedNumber $other) {
    if ($this->decimal_places != $other->decimal_places) {
      throw new Exception('Cannot subtract FixedNumber with different decimal places');
    }
    return new FixedNumber($this->value - $other->value, $this->decimal_places);
  }
  public function __mul(FixedNumber $other) {
    if ($this->decimal_places != $other->decimal_places) {
      throw new Exception('Cannot multiply FixedNumber with different decimal places');
    }
    return new FixedNumber((int)round($this->value * $other->value / self::$radix[$this->decimal_places]), $this->decimal_places);
  }
  public function __div(FixedNumber $other) {
    if ($this->decimal_places != $other->decimal_places) {
      throw new Exception('Cannot divide FixedNumber with different decimal places');
    }
    return new FixedNumber((int)round(($this->value / $other->value) * self::$radix[$this->decimal_places]), $this->decimal_places);
  }
}
```

and tried this little test setup:

```
define("SET_SIZE",1000,false);

$start = microtime(true);
$d = 0.0;
for ($i = 0; $i < SET_SIZE; ++$i) {
    $d = 40075036+86164.098903691;
}
printf('%f<br>', microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < SET_SIZE; ++$i) {
    bcadd("40075036", "86164.098903691", 16);
}
printf('%f<br>', microtime(true) - $start);

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < SET_SIZE; ++$i) {
  $a = new \FixedNumber(40075036);
  $b = new \FixedNumber(861600);
  $c = $a->__add($b);
}
printf('%f<br>', microtime(true) - $start);
```

Just to find out that although bcmath is 20 orders slower than normal math, it still outperforms my simple FixedNumber class by 0.11 order. The numbers for a set size of 1.000.000 :

```
0.009088
0.224396
0.366447
```

It appears the overhead of creating objects and being in user space makes bcmath a better deal.

It would be nice if fixed point arithmatic would be included natively for money values, school grates and the like, where floating point numbers are just wrong.